# Icon, font size in default file manager and desktop ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, icons, fonts

I have ubuntu 16.04, and 4k monitor for this system, in unity tweak tool I've added font sizes to all fields (13 size) and added zoom ratio in appearance settings to 1.75
All icons, browser, etc looks fine.

[image: how it looks]

But today something went wrong, and icons and fonts in default file manager decreased dramatically. No changes and ratios in tweak tool doesnt work.

[image]

Menu on right mouse click is also decreased in default manager and desktop.
Another manager has normal sizes, but i can't understand how to fix those fonts and icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Files on the upper right side you have three icons, click the middle icon, then you can see a slider bar just below the middle icon, moving the tab would change the icon size in the folders.